# Mac Address or IMEI on Libgdx Android App

Tags: java, android, libgdx, mac-address

I'm developing a APP to android using LIGBDX, i need to get the MAC ADDRES or IMEI or any other unique code from the phone. When using NetworkInterface from Java.net works fine on Desktop project, but on Android it doesnt work, so i saw on the internet the WifiManger,
is a API (i guess) from android.

> WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(  Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
>   WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
>   String macAddr = wifiInf.getMacAddress();

And it seens it works, BUT i'm using LIBGDX and i not getting to import Android.Net on my project, saw one guys talking when i try to references pure android on LIbgdx i have to work only on android not in Core, but i dont know how to do this. 
Maybe add Wifimanager.java into library i tried that but not work.

Note: i am using Gdx Net and edited the manifest, i am dowloading and send data from iternet, i cant do only the mac part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1)
Declare an Interface in your core project with a method to retrieve the number you want.

```
public interface IActivityRequestHandler {

    public String getUniqueId();
}
```

In your core project, add a constructor to your Game class that takes a IActivityRequestHandler as a parameter:

```
public abstract class MyGame extends Game {
     ...
     public IActivityRequestHandler handler;
     ...
     public MyGame(IActivityRequestHandler handler){
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

You will use "handler" to call platform specific methods.

2)
Make the android MainActivity implement this interface and write the methood to return the value you need.

3) In your Android MainActivity, when you instantiate your AndroidGame, pass the MainActivity as a parameter:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler{
    ...
    ApplicationListener game;
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        game = new AndroidMyGame(this);
        ...
    }
        public String getUniqueId(){
            return uniqueId;
        }
    ...
}
```

4) Now when you need the id from the core you call: handler.getUniqueId() (from MyGame class)
This will be calling the method on your Android MainActivity if you are running the game from an Android Device.

Important notes:

1) This should work if you don't have any contraints regarding the UI Thread in Android.
This is, to return a value it should work. If you call anything that can only be called in the UIThread this won't work and, aditionally, you have to use a Handler to communicate between threads.

2) Your Desktop version will also have to implement IActivityRequestHandler.

3) Getting a unique id in Android devices is something I haven't found a nice solution yet.
a) Tablets, unless they have a phone line, don't have IMEI or telephone number.
b) MAC Addresses are not unique (you have 3g, wifi, bluetooth) and sometimes are not available for example if wifi is turned off.

4) You might be better off generating a unique id yourself and storing it on the phone.
google "Java UUID".

Comment: in my case could be the mac address, becoz the app is like a online voting and the ppl needs to turn wifi on to vote, so i can get the mac adress, and yes 3G is a problem, i will handle latter. the ppl only can vote with wifi now, is life hehe.

is kind of complicated do all this stuff, hehe i will try here.

Comment: if i generate a UUID and store on the phone, if the ppl uninstall and install the app the data will be lost, or i'm wrong?

Comment: You are right. As I said I haven't found a clean solution for getting a unique id. Another thing I haven't looked into yet but may provide some solution is the Google Play licencing.

Comment: I couldnt get it work, some confused for me, there is no other way to me call wifimanager from android.net?

Comment: ERROR: Multiple markers at this line
 - overrides 
  android.app.Activity.onCreate
 - The constructor Election() is 
  undefined

But i did the constructor

public Election (IActivityRequestHandler handler){
      this.handler = handler;
  
  }